# What do i do when the Ajax form submit doesnt respond with output?

Tags: ajax

I have a form that's submitted via ajax, processed by PHP and returned with some JSON data.

The form and the ajax are working just fine, but occasionally when you click submit nothing happens on the front end. The data is still processing and being insterted into the database. But the Ajax results aren't being displayed like they normally do. If you click the submit button a second time after it does nothing the first time it usually works and displays the results properly.

Can somebody explain what's happening and how I can be sure that the form works every time?

Comment: Share your ajax code you are using.